# UIActionSheet button text not showing on iOS 8.x

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am using XCode 5.1.1 for my project. The same app in working fine for iOS 7.x. However, on iOS 8, UIActionSheet buttons do not display any text.

Here is the code:

```
addAttachmentsOptions = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                           delegate: self
                                                                  cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                                             destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                                                  otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString(@"ID_TAKE_PHOTO_LABEL", nil),
                                                NSLocalizedString(@"ID_CHOOSE_PHOTO_LABEL", nil), nil];
```

I am aware that iOS 8 doesn't supports UIActionSheet, but I would expect backward compatibility for the already published app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIActionSheet for  iOS 8 so please refer this 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to move it over to [UIAlertController's](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html). You can use an if/else to determine which to use based on current OS.